# How can i search lowercase in Azure DocumentDb?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I want to search the ID of documentdb as well as contains, starts with and ends with, but when I try to create a lowercase search.

```
await this.noSqlDataContext.GetDocumentsAsync<Index>(e => e.Id.ToLowerInvariant().Equals(key.ToLowerInvariant()));
```

I got this error :

```
"exceptionMessage": "Method 'ToLowerInvariant' is not supported.\r\nActivityId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
```

Comment: Why lowercase? Do you mean you want to compare the two strings while ignoring case?

Comment: @unrealsoul007 yes, that's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this by looking into the Azure DocumentDb documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn931798.aspx).
Using the following code for comparison:

```
e => e.Id.ToLower() == key.ToLower()
```

Comment: Note, this is a full table scan. If you need it production performance ready, I suggest that you denormalize an additional field which saved in lowercase. Then use that field for queries, which should then use an index.

Answer (score 0):

If Id and key are of type string, you can alter your lambda expression as follows:

```
(e => String.Compare(e.Id, key, true) == 0)
```

Where true sets the compare to ignore all character case.

Comment: cannot convert lambda expression to delegate return type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertable to the delegate return type.

Comment: Forgot that compare method returns an int and not a bool. Updated answer